# Event - Observer not called on Pending Order status

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

**config.xml  Code**

```
<events>
            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
                <observers>
                    <checkout_deduct_credit_amount>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>creditpoint/observer</class>
                        <method>deductCreditAmount</method>
                    </checkout_deduct_credit_amount>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <deposit_creditamount>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>creditpoint/observer</class>
                        <method>revertCreditPoints</method>
                    </deposit_creditamount>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>
        </events>
```

Here method `deductCreditAmount` is called when order is placed to deduct points spent by user from his account while `revertCreditPoints` is called
when order is refunded and to credit those spent points back to customer's account. Admin has a provision to set credit points to account balance 
when order status is `Processing/Complete/Closed`. Admin can also Restore redeemed points when order is refunded set to `Yes/No`

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 'processing', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Processing')),
            array('value' => 'complete', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Complete')),
            array('value' => 'closed', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Closed')),
        );
    }
```

Now the above works well, but to deduct points spent and credit points earned, I have added `Pending` status for admin. So that whenever an order is placed
points `debit/credit` will work without creating invoice or to wait for order status to change into `processing`.

But after setting to `Pending` status as below, it only deducts points but does not credit.

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 'new', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Pending')),
            array('value' => 'processing', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Processing')),
            array('value' => 'complete', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Complete')),
            array('value' => 'closed', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Closed')),
        );
    }
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Namespace_Creditpoint_Model_Observer {

    //this function is used to deduct credit points from customer's account after order is placed
    public function deductCreditAmount(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {


        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        $datetime = $order->getCreatedAt();

        $pointsRedeem = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('points_redeem');
        $pointsPrice = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('points_price');
        $customerCreditPoints = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getCreditPoint();


        if ($pointsRedeem && $pointsPrice != NULL) {

            //init our model, set data and save
            //deduct redeemed credit points from customer account and revise
            try {

                $revisedCreditPoints = $customerCreditPoints - $pointsRedeem;
                $creditModel = Mage::getSingleton('creditpoint/creditpoint')
                        ->setCustomerId($customerId)
                        ->setOrderId($orderId)
                        ->setAppliedCreditPoint($pointsRedeem)
                        ->setAppliedCreditPointPrice($pointsPrice)
                        ->setCreatedTime($datetime)
                        ->save();

                $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($customerId)->setCreditPoint($revisedCreditPoints)->save();

                //unset credit points data
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsEstimateCredit();
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsPointsRedeem();
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsPointsPrice();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getModel('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    //this function is used to add credit points to customer's account balance.
    public function revertCreditPoints($observer) {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        $orderStatus = Mage::helper('creditpoint')->getOrderStatus();
        $moduleStatus = Mage::helper('creditpoint')->getModuleStatus();
        $restoreConfig = Mage::helper('creditpoint')->getRestoreConfig();

        $grandTotal = round($order->getGrandTotal());
        $customerEarnedPoints = Mage::helper('creditpoint')->getCreditPointsAwarded($grandTotal);
        $customerCurrentPoints = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId())->getCreditPoint();
        $customerAppliedPoints = Mage::getSingleton('creditpoint/creditpoint')->load($order->getEntityId(), 'order_id')->getAppliedCreditPoint();


        //check if order status matches configuration order status, order is not closed, can restore points, order is closed and module is active
        if (($order->getState() == $orderStatus && $moduleStatus == 1 && $restoreConfig == 1 && $order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED) || ($restoreConfig == 1 && $order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED)) {

            try {

                $restoredPoints = ($customerCurrentPoints - $customerEarnedPoints) + $customerAppliedPoints;

                $creditModel = Mage::getSingleton('creditpoint/creditpoint')
                        ->load($order->getId(), 'order_id')
                        ->setOrderRefund($restoreConfig)
                        ->save();

                //set restored customer's points
                $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId())
                        ->setCreditPoint($restoredPoints)
                        ->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getModel('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }


            //check if order status matches configuration order status, order is not closed and module is active
        } elseif ($order->getState() == $orderStatus && $moduleStatus == 1) {

            try {

                //check if the order is placed first time OR no credit points applied on this order
                if ($customerAppliedPoints == NULL) {

                    //add earned points to current balance only     
                    $revisedCreditPoints = $customerCurrentPoints + $customerEarnedPoints;

                    $creditModel = Mage::getSingleton('creditpoint/creditpoint')
                            ->load($order->getId(), 'order_id')
                            ->setCustomerId($order->getCustomerId())
                            ->setOrderId($order->getEntityId())
                            ->setEarnedCreditPoint($customerEarnedPoints)
                            ->setCreatedTime($order->getCreatedAt())
                            ->save();

                    //set customer's credit points
                    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId())
                            ->setCreditPoint($revisedCreditPoints)
                            ->save();


                    //check if creditpoints applied on order
                } else {

                    //add earned points to current balance only     
                    $revisedCreditPoints = $customerCurrentPoints + $customerEarnedPoints;

                    $creditModel = Mage::getSingleton('creditpoint/creditpoint')
                            ->load($order->getId(), 'order_id')
                            ->setEarnedCreditPoint($customerEarnedPoints)
                            ->save();

                    //set customer's credit points
                    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId())
                            ->setCreditPoint($revisedCreditPoints)
                            ->save();
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getModel('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I do not wish to change default order status from Pending to Processing, but the business logic should work on Pending status set from admin.

If order status is set Pending from admin, it calls the event `sales_order_save_after` instead of `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after`. The logic written in observer will remain same regardless of order status but it just do not seem to be working for `Pending`

1. How do I make it work when order status is set to `Pending` ?
2. Are the events incorrectly defined and if yes, why it works for
   other order status'?

Comment: the **sales_order_save_after** is triggered whenever the order is being saving. It inherit from the Mage_Core_Model_Abstract. It should have been called **revertCreditPoints()**. The problem maybe you use **Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED** status to implement your logic. Best to add some log to record **$order->getState()**,  **$orderStatus** and **$moduleStatus**

Comment: You are true to call the other method on that event and it actually works but it fails when points are subject to be credited back to customers account in case of refund. The existing code works for processing/closed/complete status but pending.

Comment: okay, may i ask how you change the order status? massaction or in your order custom coding? care to share some code on that part?

Comment: @RaymondM, I am not changing order status. I am just initiating `revertCreditPoints` method when order is invoiced from admin i.e. when order status is changed to `Processing`.

Comment: and value of Mage::helper('creditpoint')->getOrderStatus(); is ?

Comment: @RaymondM, it will be the status set from Admin. As mentioned in code above, I have provided three options to admin. They are `Processing/Complete/Closed`. `Mage::helper('creditpoint')->getOrderStatus();` will get status set by admin from my module

Comment: sorry, cant help you. try adding log.

Comment: There will no error log as issue is with method initiation on order status Pending

Comment: not error log. You can add log using `Mage::log('message here' , null , 'mylog.log');` . mylog.log will be created in folder magento_root/var/log/